# RegEx on Javascript; Checking for instances of one of multiple strings

Tags: javascript, regex, forms

I have done a lot of server side form validation but until now, the only client side form validation I have done is to check for null/blank entries (e.g., if (value==''||value==null)  ). I am now checking for user-entered vulgarities and have found success checking for these (incorporated into one variable - vulgarcheck) using javascript as follows:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function CheckUserForm() {
var usersuggestion=document.forms['UserForm']['userinput'].value;
var vulgarcheck = /badword1|badword2|badword3|etc/gi;
var vulgarcompare = usersuggestion.match(vulgarcheck);

if (usersuggestion==''||usersuggestion==null) {
alert('To make a suggestion, please enter text into the textbox');
return false;
}
else if (vulgarcompare!=null) {
alert('The text you entered contains some vulgar language. Please try again!');
return false;
}
else {
return true;
}
}
</script>
```

Since I am new to javascript form validation more complex than a check for a null/blank-entry, I was hoping someone could tell me if my method has any oversight that I am not aware of. That is, are there potential problems with this method that I am missing? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Looks alright but `if (vulgarcheck.test(usersuggestion)) {...}` is better since `test` returns a boolean true/false.

Comment: This is a lost battle, what happens when someone types Dick Cheney and is censored, or ....... **pussy** -cat, **ass** -assin, **ass** -emble,  etc

Comment: The main issue with checking for vulgarities is that it is hard to avoid false positives - if you check for the presense of the word "ass" you will block "classic" and "assassinate".  If you block the word cum, what happens when someone mentions that they were a magna cum laude graduate?  And then, what about when someone write f-u-c-k?  Is that going to be allowed, or do you start checking for that?  The best way to handle this is to simply have a flag this post as offensive button, and then either say after 3 votes it gets deleted, or you review anytime a post gets flagged.

Comment: Thank you for the great answers. I will check .test to see if this would be better for my site. No special characters would also be implemented....I have implemented this server side so this would take away user input such as s-h-i-t and any variations of this and other similarly-constructed vulgarities. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Also, good point @dave on substrings like "ass" that block legitimate words such as "classic". My solution is to not match on the string "ass" but match on the entire string "assbleep" as a vulgarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that maintaining you dictionary with vulgar words would be hard in near future, when you would like add more and more words.

My proposal is to build up an dictionary and use dictionary lookup. John Resig wrote two good articles about this things: http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-trie-performance-analysis/ and
http://ejohn.org/blog/dictionary-lookups-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below to check for validation not null, not blank, not undefined and not zero in javascript and jquery.

```
 function myFunction() {
    var data;  //The Values can be like as null,blank,undefined,zero you can test

     if(!(!(data)))
     {
     alert("data "+data);
     } 
     else 
     {
        alert("data is "+data);
    }

    }
```